# How to make a column in a joined layer editable?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, editing, attribute-joins

I have layer1 from postgresql which has is joined to layer2. Most users work on layer1 but there is a column on layer2 which needs to be updated by users of layer1

Without making layer2 fully available, I wanted to just have this this column showing as part of layer1

Now I've tried 2 different approaches:

- join the layers first and toggle editable join layer. Then go into attributes form and try and drag the join layer into the form. QGIS completely freezes when I left click the field
- join the layers without toggling editable join layer. Then to into attributes, successfully add the field, then go back to the join and toggle on editable join layer and QGIS freezes then

Am I doing something wrong or is there an alternate solution for users to updating layer2 from layer1?

Comment: Instead of the client being responsible for the (non-native) relational update, create a *View* of the join and implement `INSTEAD OF` triggers. Faster and simply, more precise permission handling (i.e. just add that one column of layer2 to the `JOIN`).